# Syntax error : unexpected end of file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm Writing the following code :

```
. smtp.config
SEND_MAIL(){
cat $BODY |mailx -s "report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`"  $TO_LIST -c $CC_LIST << $REPORTS_PATH ;
};
if [ ${#REPORTS_PATH[@]} -gt 0 ] then
SEND_MAIL;
echo  MAIL SENT : `date`  >> $LOG_FILE ;
mkdir $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'` ;
mv $REPORTS_PATH/* $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'` ;
echo done ;
fi
```

when i run the script it gives me :

```
./mail.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

the other thing is can i replace this part :  `if [ ${#REPORTS_PATH[@]} -gt 0 ]`  with another syntax 
(this part i'm using to check if the directory contains file or empty .

Comment: Take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thanks but still it's giving unexpected end of file with no fix

Comment: Remove `<< $REPORTS_PATH`.

Comment: Correct syntax of if command is this: `if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; fi`

Answer (score 0):

```
. smtp.config
SEND_MAIL(){
cat $BODY |mailx -s "report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`"  $TO_LIST -c $CC_LIST << $REPORTS_PATH
}
if [ ${#REPORTS_PATH[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
SEND_MAIL
echo  MAIL SENT : `date`  >> $LOG_FILE
mkdir $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`
mv $REPORTS_PATH/* $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`
echo done
fi
```

You don't need a semicolon if you make a new line for a new command. You only need it if you run several commands on the same line.

But that wasn't the issue, it's just optional. Your issue was the forgotten semicolon after the closing `]` bracket at the if statement. If you want to avoid the semicolon there, just write `then` solo on the next line.

```
. smtp.config
SEND_MAIL(){
cat $BODY |mailx -s "report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`"  $TO_LIST -c $CC_LIST << $REPORTS_PATH
}
if [ ${#REPORTS_PATH[@]} -gt 0 ]
then
SEND_MAIL
echo  MAIL SENT : `date`  >> $LOG_FILE
mkdir $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`
mv $REPORTS_PATH/* $REPORTS_ARCHIVE/report_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%s'`
echo done
fi
```

Comment: @Mohamed Yasser Have you tried my solution yet? Or has your question been answered by a comment?